# aggregations query: How do i aggregate and get back multiple values with document count?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have multiple elastic documents, with fields "cityId", "cityName". I want to count occurrences of documents with specific "cityId" and "cityName".

Aggregation query to fetch cityId and count:

```
GET _search
{
  "aggs": {
    "CityIdCount": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cityId",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
...........................
```

This is the existing query and it gives the result as (key as cityId and doc_count as number of occurrences:
{
               "key": 40,
               "doc_count": 4906
},

This is query i tried to fetch (cityId,cityName,doc_count) and it gives the result as (key as cityName and doc_count as number of occurrences of that name:  {
               "key": "Thane",
               "doc_count": 4906
            }

```
GET _search
{
  "aggs": {
    "CityIdCount": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cityId",
        "field": "cityName",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
   ..............................
```

I want all together, example: "cityId","cityName","doc_count".

What would be the correct query for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't (*currently at least*) perform a terms aggregation across a conjunction of multiple fields in the way that you're suggesting. You can do it in one of two ways:

1. Use a [`terms` aggregation with a script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) that concatenates the fields on which you want to perform the aggregation. This may perform well enough for your use case, but be aware that you are paying a performance cost at query time.
2. Combine the field values on which you want to perform the aggregation at index time into a new `not_analyzed` field e.g. `cityIdAndName` either in your application or using [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) and use the terms aggregation on this field. This will perform much better than the first option at the cost of indexing more data.